# How to Prevent CSRF in Play [2.0] Using Scala?

Tags: security, scala, playframework, csrf, playframework-2.0

A lot of web frameworks have a standard setup for generating forms with auth tokens.

Do I have to create such measures manually, or does Play come with a build in means of prevening CSRF?

The documentation on the [Play website](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaFormHelpers) doesn't seem to address this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use the [play2-authenticitytoken](https://github.com/orefalo/play2-authenticitytoken) module:

> The authenticity token is a way around one of the most serious internet security threats: CRSF attacks. It ensures that the client submitting a form is the one who received the page (and not a hacker who stole your session data).

How it works:

> In a nutshell:
>
> 1. on every form post, we add a hidden parameter containing a uuid
> 2. the uuid is signed and its signature is stored in the session (which translated into a cookie)
>
> When the user submits the form, we get: the uuid, the signature and the other form inputs.
>
> 1. We sign the incoming uuid again
> 2. Validation passes if the signatures match (session.sign=uuid.sign)
>
> Should an attacker inject a different id, he will never figure how to generate the correct signature.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but the best way around XSS is to go full HTTPS, right ?

Comment: @OlivierRefalo HTTPS doesn't stop XSS attacks, it only protects the data in transit. You could google for "XSS HTTPS" and you'd find  e.g. [this](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-xss/) and [an article by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-secxss/)

Comment: @user166390 : This approach will not stop the climate change either. XSS is mitigated at another level.

Answer (score 8):

For completeness sake, I have an example here in Scala for Play 2.0

- https://github.com/jacobgroundwater/Scala-Play-CSRF

This method also uses the cookie + hidden-field approach.

### Example Usage

Use the `SessionKey` action to help sign a form:

```
object Application extends Controller {
    def login = SessionKey{ (key,signature) => 
        Action { implicit request =>
            Ok( views.html.login(signature) ).withSession( key->signature )
        }
    }
}
```

When parsing forms use the following to check for the signature:

```
object Authenticator extends Controller {
    def login = ValidateForm{ 
        Action { implicit request =>
            Ok( views.html.index("You're Loggd In") )
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since Play 2.1 there's support for this in the framework. Nick Carroll wrote a nice little article on how to use it:

http://nickcarroll.me/2013/02/11/protect-your-play-application-with-the-csrf-filter/